# AH00686: cannot read directory for multi: /var/www/../web/

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

I have a problem. I have `ispconfig` and i have a lot of sites. If i make from beginning the joomla installation, the site works fine. When i moved from another server that i have 6 sites, the 3 of them works fine but the other 3 i get an empty page with the word error. I try to search the solution but i didnt find anything. Only that perhaps it must be from `apache2/php`.

I see the error log and the error that says there is:

```
[Mon Jan 10 14:38:08.064460 2022] [negotiation:error] [pid 3501998] (13)Permission denied: [client myip:port] AH00686: cannot read directory for multi: /var/www/mysite/web/
```

I have done some changes to `.htaccess` and `php.ini` but neither worked.

Ubuntu version is 20.04.3.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this happens when there are file permission issues. You will want to ensure that all files and directories for the site are owned by Apache:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/mysite
```

<sup>**Note:** This will set ownership on every file and directory within `/var/www/mysite`.</sup>

Comment: Yes i check that you said, but i made the same steps that i have done to all the other sites that they are working. Also the permissions are the same with the other sites that are working. Any other solution please? Thank you in advance

Comment: There is not enough information about your server configuration to offer more specific solutions. Will your AppArmor configuration allow Apache to use `/var/web` instead of `/var/www`? Is the virtual host configuration pointed correctly? Are there any symlinks that might be causing trouble? You'll need to do a bunch of digging through your logs to see what the exact issue is 